# How to create ssl connection to mysql with gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Can't seem to find any resource on creating a SSL connection to mysql using gorm. I am creating a non-ssl connection like this:

```
cfg := mysql.Config{
    User:   config.User,
    Passwd: config.Password,
    Addr:   fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", config.Host, config.Port),
    Net:    "tcp",
    Params: options,
}

str := cfg.FormatDSN()
db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", str)
```

Passing 'ssl-ca' option in Param options with path to 'pem' file does not seem to work. Any heads up on this?

Comment: Can you print the string that results just to check what it looks like?

Comment: @Ullaakut The connection string looks like this: root:pass@tcp(localhost:3306)/?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&allowNativePasswords=True&ssl-ca=%27ca.pem%27

Comment: The issue is probably that as you can see the path given is just `ca.pem` so it just can't find the file.

Comment: @Ullaakut The path I have provided is correct. I have provided the trimmed version of string with only the pem file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fragment of my working code :

```
isTLS := false

if mysqlClientKey != "" && mysqlCaCert != ""  && mysqlClientCert != "" {
    isTLS = true
    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/mysqlCaCert")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
    }
    clientCert := make([]tls.Certificate, 0, 1)
    certs, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("/path/mysqlClientCert", "/path/mysqlClientKey")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    clientCert = append(clientCert, certs)
    mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:      rootCertPool,
        Certificates: clientCert,
    })
}

// try to connect to mysql database.
cfg := mysql.Config{
    User:   username,
    Passwd: password,
    Addr:   server, //IP:PORT
    Net:    "tcp",
    DBName: database,
    Loc: time.Local,
    AllowNativePasswords: true,
    Params: o,
}

if isTLS == true {
    cfg.TLSConfig = "custom"
}

str := cfg.FormatDSN()

db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", str)
```

Comment: Assume that "mysqlCaCert" is from different server and "mysqlClientCert" and "mysqlClientKey" from same server on which I want to do connection. Now the connection is occurred which is wrong.